# how to get the next immediate following-sibling of particular node in xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is my xml document.

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w">

      <w:body>
                 <w:p>
        <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/></w:pPr>
        <w:r><w:t>Tables</w:t></w:r>  <!-- Assume Current Node here --> 
                  </w:p>
                  <w:tbl>
                        <w:tr>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
               <w:r><w:t>row1col</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row1co2</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                           </w:tr>

    <w:tr>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row2col1</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row2col2</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                           </w:tr>
              </w:tbl>

                 <w:p>
        <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/></w:pPr>
        <w:r><w:t>2nd table</w:t></w:r> 
                  </w:p>           

           <w:tbl>
                        <w:tr>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row11col11</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row11co12</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                           </w:tr>
        <w:tr>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row12col11</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                               <w:tc>
                                     <w:p>
                                         <w:r><w:t>row12col12</w:t></w:r>
                                      </w:p>
                                   </w:tc>
                           </w:tr>
              </w:tbl>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

So, I want to transform this xml file to given format.

```
<Document>
<Heading1>
<title>Tables</title>
<table>
   <paragraph>row1col1</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row1col2</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row2col1</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row2col2</paragraph>
</table>
<paragraph>2nd Table</paragraph>
<table>
   <paragraph>row11col11</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row11col12</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row12col11</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row12col12</paragraph>
</table>
</Heading1>
</Document>
```

I have done almost done everything except below mentioned case.Assume now current node is first `<w:p>`(Mentioned in xml Document).So, for getting table items, i coded like

```
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="following-sibling::w:tbl//w:p[w:r[w:t]]" >

         <table>
              <!--some code  here -->
          </table>
       </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
```

but, while doing so, the output is like...

```
<table>
       <paragraph>row1col1</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row1col2</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row2col1</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row2col2</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row11col11</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row11col12</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row12col11</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row12col12</paragraph>
</table>
```

I want to group each and every table in separate table node.How i do it? Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: You want to do other things as well. Just do a for-each of the w:tbl elements and add any preceding elements if needed.

Comment: @FailedDev:: thanks, i will try to implement your idea.If you found the way then plz let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment in your XSLT, it suggests you are positioned on the **w:r** element, but your XSLT snippet suggests you are actually positioned on the **w:p** element.

Assuming your current node is **w:p** if you want to get the first **w:tbl** element that follows it, you can do the following

```
<xsl:when test="following-sibling::w:tbl[1]//w:p[w:r[w:t]]" >
```

However, it sounds like you only want to find the first **w:tbl** element if it immediately follows the **w:p** (i.e the first element that follows the **w:p** is the **w:tbl** element). In this case, you probably want to do the following

```
<xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][self::w:tbl]//w:p[w:r[w:t]]" >
```

Comment: thanks a lot Tim...It is working perfectly.But the "2nd table" comes under the table2.How to keep the same order...

Comment: It is hard to say because you haven't shown the full XSLT. You might need to ask a new a question if you are having other problems. Thanks.